# Pandas - convert the list of string to list of integer

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, exception

I have a dataframe like this:

```
| customerID| clickHistory |
| -------- | -------------- |
| A    | []            |
| B   | ['85','14','23']            |
| C | [] |
```

and I want this table to be:

```
| customerID| clickHistory |
| -------- | -------------- |
| A    | []            |
| B   | [85,14,23]            |
| C | [] |
```

I tried with

```
df['clickHistory'] = [[int(x) for x in l] for l in df['clickHistory'] if len(l) > 0]
```

but it returns an error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I tried it without if len(l) > 0 but still seeing same error.

How should I handle that empty list during this type conversion?

Comment: Add a conditional: `[int(x) for x in l if x] for l in df['clickHistory'] if len(l) > 0]`

Comment: Thank you!! I should study list comprehension more